# Wrapping an iOS framework in Swift CLI compatible framework

Tags: ios, swift, console, frameworks

So I'm trying to use [this article](https://medium.com/livefront/how-to-add-a-dynamic-swift-framework-to-a-command-line-tool-bab6426d6c31) (option 3B) to take an existing iOS framework and use it with a Swift Console App. However, the linker still can't seem to find the wrapper framework:

> ld: framework not found CLI_Wrapper0
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

In the new wrapper framework, I linked the original framework in the General tab of the primary target. I changed the wrapper's Build Settings:

```
//:configuration = Debug
ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = YES

//:configuration = Release
ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = YES

//:completeSettings = some
ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES
```

Finally I added a Copy Files step to Build Phases and set it up to copy the original framework into the wrapper's "Frameworks" destination. There is nothing in the wrapper framework's run path Search Paths.

Now in the console app, I removed the dependency to the original framework and linked the new wrapper library in the general tab. And in the User Defined Build Settings:

```
//:configuration = Debug
SWIFT_FORCE_DYNAMIC_LINK_STDLIB = YES
SWIFT_FORCE_STATIC_LINK_STDLIB = NO

//:configuration = Release
SWIFT_FORCE_DYNAMIC_LINK_STDLIB = YES
SWIFT_FORCE_STATIC_LINK_STDLIB = NO

//:completeSettings = some
SWIFT_FORCE_DYNAMIC_LINK_STDLIB
SWIFT_FORCE_STATIC_LINK_STDLIB
```

And in the console app's run path search path I added (##### = original framework):

```
//:configuration = Debug
LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = @executable_path/#####.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks

//:configuration = Release
LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = @executable_path/#####.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks

//:completeSettings = some
LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS
```

**Did I put something in the wrong place (I tried to make sure I updated the correct app/framework's settings) or is the path I'm using bad?** Any help would be appreciated.